How to make Geonodes understand that an index sequence is a selection?
I've done some fancy math to achieve a specific index sequence and I want Blender to understand that this sequence is a selection of indices. When I input them to a compare node, only the indices that have the same number get selected. That's not what I want, I want the the index sequence itself to be the selector of the indices, like a boolean of indices.
So if my sequence is '0,2,4,8,16...' I want a boolean of these values in this format: 'TFTFTFFFTFFFFFFFT...' Is it possible?

Well, use a Repeat Zone looping on your indices to output either T or F ? It's hard to be more precise without having details on your setup.

You should rephrase your question to show the problem you're trying to solve, not describing the exact solution you've found and asking us how to make that work. The latter is often an XY Problem in disguise. Not to mention just describing a bunch of math and booleans via text is confusing for the reader.

The idea is to extrude only some parts of a geometry, but as the indices are so particular, I can't come up with any modulo, which would do for the selection, rather I'm forging a new index sequence, but I don't know if there is a way to make this sequence to be a selection. In this case, the selection sequence has to be '0,8,12,20,24,32,36,...' If there is a way to performe a modulo operation of such sequence than I  would love to hear that, please.

This sequence is the same for every case I'll need in the future.

When you want to go in a slightly different way, making a boolean list and specifying for all values if they are selected, arbitrarily, I have a roadsign to various approaches here: Geometry node angled line creation

$0, 2, 4, 8, 16...$ looks like a sequence of powers of $2$, without $1$:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Mentioned in comments $0, 8, 12, 20, 24, 32, 36...$ looks like two sequences of multiples of 12, one offset by 8:
0,    12,     24,     36...
   8,     20,     32


Imgur mirror
But I get it, sometimes you just need arbitrary sequence...

Imgur mirror
And if you really want to parse a string because you want to provide an easy to use interface, then you need to use the tools available to parse it:

Imgur mirror
Notice how there needs to be a comma at the end of the string, as it tells the stack machine to output a number as a point. You can just add a comma to an input though... Of course for a professional usage you might want to check the string for errors and report that, also support spaces (just remove them or replace with commas and remove double commas to support space separation...) etc.


Wow, it totally worked, but how?? Analysing the two fractions they did completely different results... the 'not equal' math should trigger for every index, how is this possible? And how did you come up with the idea? Teach me please! Amazing!

@AAAYerus what you're missing is the implicit coercion of float to boolean. Explaining my methods of analysis and problem solving would take more space than comments allow.

Freaking genius. I keep struggling to understand all this context and attribute caputre/transfer stuff and then this....

@DanielMöller I also struggled a lot understanding geonodes, this is why I wrote some posts thoroughly going through how the node tree evaluates, that I wish existed when I started: What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry even then still you can "translate" from A (nodes) to B (effect), but when you know B (desired effect), it's hard to translate it to A, without experience you need to just run through various As in your head until you realize "yep, that's the one that translates to B" :D

Yeah, I figured that out recently. Basically the last node that receives the geometry input is the king, it's like a reverse hierarchy. Everything that comes before have to adapt to the next node's index sequence. So when u capture a previous node's attribute it's because it has the logic a following node needs. It's basically stealing.
